# How to pop up a textarea while clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a pop up window which shows one ore more paragraphs.

My requirement is, I have a 'Read more' link.

```
<a href='#' onclick='read_more()'>Read More</a>
```

While clicking on this link, I want a pop up window which shows the detailed contents. How can I do this?

Comment: if you use jQuery, this is easy and pretty http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Your question is very unclear! Please provide a better description.

Comment: I have some contents to be displayed. But it should be displayed in a pop up box while clicking the read more link...

Answer (score 5):

If you want a real pop-up (not a dialog):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function read_more() {
    window.open('my_page.html');
}
</script>
```

**window.open**

> Creates a new secondary browser window and loads the referenced resource.

You can read more about this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this code. However, I recommend using JQuery, as @ericosg writes

```
<div id="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 10; top: 10">
POST YOUR TEXT HERE
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function read_more()
{
  var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

  popup.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function read_more() {
    window.open('myPage.html');
}
</script>

<a href="javascript: read_more()" >Read More</a>
```